# Understanding Conditional Probability Basics

Tags: probability, bayesian

In many online sources I've read a statement similar to:

> Probability of B happening given A is equal to the probability of A and B both happening divided by B happening

or

$p(A | B) = p(A \cap B) / p(B)$

But what is the difference between "B happening given A" and "A and B happening at the same time" ? If B happens given A, didn't A and B happen at the same time ? Why is that chance smaller than the intersection ?

Comment: The formula is right. But the statement is not right. It has to be: "Probability of $A$ happening given $B$ is equal to the probability of A and B both happening divided by B happening."

Comment: $P(A|B)$ isn´t smaller than $P(A\cap B)$. $P(B)\cdot P(A|B)=P(A \cap B)$ and $P(B) \leq 1$. Thus $P(A|B)\geq P(A \cap B)$

Comment: @calculus I am aware that the probability of B given some observations is going to reduce chances of A happening given B as a condition condition, but the problem is the play of words when stating the formula such as "both happening" and "this happening given that" is what I find confusing.

Comment: I understood your questions. I only make comments on you false statements. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @pwned **calculus**'s point is a good one.  Your confusion seemed to be about the difference between "A _and_ B" vs. "A given B".  You noted that "A _given_ B" sort of entails "A _and_ B".  **calculus** explained that your intuition is partly correct which is that "A _given_ B" must be _at least_ as probable as "A _and_ B".  The point is that, in a sense, "A _given_ B" is a "weaker" condition than "A _and_ B".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"If B happens given A, didn't A and B happen at the same time?"*  Yes that is true (or it could be true--it could also be considering sequential events--not necessarily simultaneous ones).  However, A and B happening together might be "unlikely" (really it just means they might not always happen together).

So consider that you have three outcomes and *exactly* two always occur together.  That is there are three possible outcomes: A and B, A and C, or B and C.  Now what is the probability that A occurs given that B occurs?  Well the probability that they *both* occur is $\frac{1}{3}$ (since A and B is only one possible outcome out of three).  But what is the probability that *given that B occurs* that A occurs?  Well there are only *two* events such that B occurs: either A and B or B and C.  Therefore *given that B occurs* the probability that A *also* occurs is $\frac{1}{2}$ (because you have excluded the possibility that A and C occur since you assumed B occurred).

This is indeed inline with [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem).  The probability of B occurring is $\frac{2}{3}$ and the probability of A *and* B occurring is $\frac{1}{3}$ therefore the probability of A given B is: $\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}$. (this is probably a poor example of Bayes' Theorem because, in this case, if you chose any two events, you'd always get $p(x|y \neq x) = \frac{1}{2}$)

**Second Example: Independent Events**

Consider that you flip a (fair) coin twice, sequentially.  What are the possible outcomes?  You can have $\{HH, TT, HT, TH\}$ (since it's a *fair* coin, each of these possibilities are equally likely--that's important here although we could extend to situations where they are *not* equally likely--but then we start getting more into the Bernoulli random variable rather than conditional probabilities).  What is the probability that you get a heads on the first flip?  Clearly from the above we get $\frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Now, what is the probability that you flip a heads given that the first flip is heads?  There is only a single outcome that satisfies this (i.e. that you get two heads in a row).  However there is only *one other* event, $HT$, such that heads was rolled first, therefore the probability that you get a heads given that the first flip was heads is $\frac{1}{2}$.  Again, this is the same as the probability of two heads (heads both times), $\frac{1}{4}$, divided by the probability of getting heads the first time, $\frac{2}{4}$: $\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{2}{4}} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Indeed we see by the above that the probability of getting heads given an initial flip of heads is the *same* as the probability of getting heads on the second roll--both are $\frac{1}{2}$.  This tells us that each flip is *independent* of the other since the probability of getting heads isn't affected by the previous flip.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in one case, you already know B has happened. This is not subject to chance anymore, it's a fact. So you compute the probability of A happening, knowing for a fact that B happened

For the probability in the intersection, on the other hand, you don't know that B has happened and have to calculate the probability that both A and B occur